# Why am I getting an error when using a decorator with my factorial function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I've been trying to understand decorators a little better. I'm confused why I'm getting an error using my timer decorator on my factorial function. My factorial function works independently. I'm thinking maybe it's because the decorator is returning something as well as the factorial function. This is the error I'm receiving:
[image]

Code for my decorator:

```
def timer(func):
    """A decorator that prints how long a function took to run.
    
    Args:
        func (callable): The function being decorated.
        
    Returns:
        callable: The decorated function."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # when wrapper is called, get the current time.
        t_start = time.time()
        # call the decorated function and store the result
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # get the total time it took to run, and print it.
        t_total = time.time() - t_start
        print(f"{func.__name__} took {t_total}s")
    return wrapper
```

Code for my quick factorial function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0: 
        return 1
    else:
        return (n * factorial(n-1))
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The wrapped function doesn't explicitly `return` anything, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Your `wrapper` function does not return its `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper function is not returning anything, thus the error about the unsupported operation between int and NoneType (since a function without return statemet actually returns None). You need to add `return result` as last statement to your wrapper function.
Your decorator should look like this:

```
def timer(func): 
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    # when wrapper is called, get the current time.
    t_start = time.time()
    # call the decorated function and store the result
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    # get the total time it took to run, and print it.
    t_total = time.time() - t_start
    print(f"{func.__name__} took {t_total}s")
    return result
  return wrapper
```

Comment: I didn't even realize I didn't return anything. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `wrapper` should `return` the local variable `result`.

Right now, it does not return anything explicitly, so it implicitly returns `None`.